# can multiplication of S3 group of permutations

Tags: matrices, permutations

I have two matrices which are all permutations $C = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1& 0& 0\\0 & 0 &1\end{pmatrix}$and $ A=  \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0& 1& 0\\1 & 0 &0\end{pmatrix}$of the identity matrix. The question I want to answer is :
Is it possible to create the remaining four matrices in this $S_3$ group. Also, can other permutations  be generated from matrix products $\otimes$ of these two?

I have computed $C^2$ and I got a (321) permutation $C^3$ led to the identity matrix. So I concluded that no, it is impossible. $A^2 \rightarrow I_3$

On the matrix product part, I simply considered the fact that the product will be a 9 x 9 matrix and I said no.

Comment: The matrix product of two $3$x$3$ matrices is still $3$x$3$.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You seem to know cycle notation for permutations (if not, look it up). Then $C$ corresponds to $(12)$ and $A$ to $(13)$. It's easy to show those two transpositions generate all of $S_3$.

Comment: thank you Ethan and Harto

Answer (score 1):

You can easily write down the group $S_3=\langle A,C\rangle$ with the usual matrix product, and not with the Kronecker product.

Comment: you mean by multiplying the two? If so, must I then square , cube....the answer until I get to the identity matrix? Thank you for your hint.

Comment: Yes. Note that $AC$ has order $3$, and $A$ and $C$ have order $2$, i.e., $A^2=C^2=I$, and $(AC)^3=(CA)^3=I$.

Comment: Hah! Thanks a million @Dietrich